# Creating Multiple Buttons Based on NSNumber Value

Tags: objective-c, uibutton, nsnumber

I'm trying to create a number of buttons that will align vertically, but my code does not seem to be working. When i try the simulator, nothing appears. This is my code:

```
        NSInteger i;
for (i = 1; i <= oneValue.integerValue; i++) {
    UIButton *buttonOne = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 450 - (30 * i), 25, 25)];
    [buttonOne setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Dark Circle.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [buttonOne setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Dark Circle Highlighted.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
}
```

The NSNumber "oneValue" is retrieved from previous user input and is an integer from 1 to 20.

Comment: You need to add those buttons to your view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the buttons to their super view. If that code is executed in a `UIViewController`, then it should be:

```
NSInteger i;
for (i = 1; i <= oneValue.integerValue; i++) {
    UIButton *buttonOne = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 450 - (30 * i), 25, 25)];
    [buttonOne setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Dark Circle.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [buttonOne setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Dark Circle Highlighted.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    [self.view addSubview:buttonOne];
}
```